# Flask-SQLAlchemy - SQL operations

Tags: python

Am using Flask with Flask-SQLAlchemy, for the SQL operations, i can able to successfully insert a record into mysql database from the

Views.py

```
from models import *
user= adduser('test')
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

models.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import app
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class adduser(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'adduser'
id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
UserName = db.Column(db.String(16))

def __init__(self, UserName):
    self.UserName = UserName
```

How to do the same operation in a separate Python file (suppose i want to handle the insert operation in a file other than views.py, say insertuser.py)

Comment: Just do it the same way you did in views.py? =) Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Moodh, when  i try to import model into the new file, am getting error while starting the server. Error - cannot import app

Comment: @user2104391 What is your files/dirs structure? I once faced such a problem when I wanted to access the `app` in import when the app file was withing a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Create your project as a package with `___init__.py`. Then you just need to initialize the "app", "db",  variables once and can re-use. Something like:

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    insertuser.py
```

Now, in your `__init__.py` file, put the initialization code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Then just import these in the insertuser.py file:

```
from myproject import app, db
..insert code goes here...
```